# Base64 JAVA encode with dynamic values in SCALA - GATLING

Tags: java, scala, encoding, base64, gatling

I'm USING GATLING AND trying to use in java's library "Base64" in scala for sending encode uder:password in header ("authorization") request, with dynamic values:
I'm trying to do as follow :

```
 val register = {
    exec(request.asJSON
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(jsonPath("$..user").saveAs("user"))
      .check(jsonPath("$..password").saveAs("password"))
    ).pause(1)
  }


      val myvalue: HttpRequestBuilder = Utils.createPostFormParamsRequest(
        "myvalue",
        login,
        Map("value"-> ("Basic " + Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString((("${user}").getBytes() + ":" + ("${password}").getBytes()).getBytes("utf-8")))),
        Map())
```

I'd tried also `Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(("${uesr}" + ":" + "${password}").getBytes("utf-8"))))`

But it seems like the Base64 take the String `"${user}"` and not the actual value, so the encryption does not work properly.

I'd tried to :

```
val helper = {
  exec { session =>
  val user : String= (session("user").as[String])
  val password : String= (session("password").as[String])

  val  temp = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString((user + ":" + password).getBytes("utf-8"))
  val temp2: HttpRequestBuilder = Utils.createPostFormParamsRequest(
  "bla",
  login,
  Map("value"-> temp),
  Map())

  val assert = {
  exec(helper.asJSON
  .check(status.is(200))
  .check(header("answer").saveAs("answer"))
  ).pause(1)
}
  session
}
```

And here the encryption works properly, but the "exec" do not.

There is a way to save the values in run time without part of the exec?

Comment: Try changing `val finalToken` to `def finalToken` and see if it makes a difference. I'm just wondering if the value is being resolved when the class is instantiated rather than when it's called (after the session variables have been set).

Comment: I tried, it still does not work :( @eurotrash

Comment: In that case it may be that you're using it incorrectly. Maybe the `${}` syntax only works within an `exec`. You'd have to check the documentation on that.  I'll post an answer with a possible alternative solution.

Comment: Its doesn't works only   within an exec cause i did the following:

`val registerReq : HttpRequestBuilder = Utils.createPostBodyRequest(
    "Register",
    Constants.REGISTER_API_V3,
    Map("Content-Type"-> "application/json", "Authorization"-> "${lihitoken}"),
    ElFileBody("ProtectorRegistrationDTO.json"))`

And it works

Comment: Is `getBytes()` not `getBytes(System.getProperty("file.encoding"))` hence platform dependent, and possibly erroneous for UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Gatling that well, but I think this should work. It's not the prettiest but without seeing the full code and how it's used it's a bit difficult to come up with something that looks good:

```
var token: String = null
val registerAssert = exec(...)
def finalToken = {
    Utils.createPostFormParamsRequest(
        "Final token",
        Constants.LOGIN,
        Map("Authorization"-> token),
        Map())
}
def saveToken(s: Session) = {
    token = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString((s("uuid").as[String].getBytes() + ":" + s("secret").as[String].getBytes()).getBytes("utf-8")
    s
}

// now you're actually executing the above

scenario(...)
.exec(registerAssert)
.exec(saveToken(_))
.exec(finalToken) // I'm assuming finalToken is executable
```

The intention of this is to first save the token value in a class variable, and then only construct the `finalToken` request (which uses that token) afterwards. Hence the `def`, and when it's called the `token` value will have been set.